# Single SCSS rule showing 'undefined' on server but works in localhost

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, code-splitting, parceljs

I have an app built using React with Parcel. I am attempting code splitting via modules, but have a strange issue.

On my home page, I am importing a module that has its own css. When the component is showing on the page, there is one single css rule that is showing as 'undefined' in the inspector.

When I run this in my local, or on another page in my app such as About, the rule is recognized and everything works perfectly.

I've tried everything I can think of, but I am lost as to what to try next.

Here's the code in my js file:

```
<div className={styles.content__move + " content__move"}>
  <div className={styles.columns + " columns"}>
    <div className={styles.column + " column"}>
```

The rule being ignored is 'styles.columns'. As you can see it is in between styles.content__move and styles.column, and BOTH of those are working as expected.

When inspecting I see this:

```
<div class="_content__move_31d79 content__move">
  <div class="undefined columns">
    <div class="_column_31d79 column">
      <div class="_column__img_31d79  column__img _bg4_31d79">
```

But if I add the module on another page, it shows correctly as:

```
<div class="_content__move_31d79 content__move">
  <div class="_columns_31d79 columns">
    <div class="_column_31d79 column">
      <div class="_column__img_31d79  column__img _bg4_31d79">
```

What might I be missing?

Comment: Has the SSR existed on your project?

Comment: It has not, these are the first builds on this server.

Comment: I had this issue on one of my projects, that project has SSR and I used Webpack for bundling, after all, I realized on server webpack config I should use `isomorphic-style-loader` instead of `style-loader`. the `style-loader` is just for client configuration. But for Parcel, I have no idea. maybe you should do something like me.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. Parcel being so similar to WebPack, I think you might be on to something. I appreciate the feedback very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was, but I renamed the class in the JS and CSS, rebuilt, and it started working right away. I would suggest to try this before changing style loaders for anybody that has the same problem.

I added:

```
class="styles.columns_f"
```

in the JS, and in the SCSS:

```
.columns_f {...}
```

Ran a production build, and that was the fix.

Comment: does your app still work if you now revert the change? did you just have something stale in your Parcel build cache?

Comment: @DanO, it must have been something with the Parcel build cache, because it does work when I revert the change.